# How do i Solve the following error while runnin npm install mysqljs/mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I wanted to install the Mysql into my node.js project. I tried to install it using these commands

```
npm install mysqljs/mysql
npm install mysql
```

but I got the following error

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\cbshr\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\cbshr\package.json'
npm WARN cbshr No description
npm WARN cbshr No repository field.
npm WARN cbshr No README data
npm WARN cbshr No license field.


npm install mysqljs/mysql
npm install mysql


npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\cbshr\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\cbshr\package.json'
npm WARN cbshr No description
npm WARN cbshr No repository field.
npm WARN cbshr No README data
npm WARN cbshr No license field.
```

Comment: can you print what directory you're in and what the contents of that directory are?

Comment: i have got following folders and files in my directory  1. node_modules(folder) 2. myfirstnode.js 3. package-lock.JASON

Comment: @CBShrestha What is the path to that directory?

Comment: @Tanner  D:\node js

Comment: In your command window, type cd `D:\node js` then your `npm install` commands - see if that works for you.

Comment: ( D:\node js>npm install mysql ) its showing the same error @Tanner

Comment: You'll need to locate the package.json for your nodejs project and run the `npm install` commands from the directory it is in. 

If you do not have one, refer to https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file for help creating / generating one

Comment: Yeah it appears the app wasn't initialized correctly and is missing that file

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your terminal from the folder that contains your project. Based on the message, the terminal is running from `C:\Users\cbshr\`.

In Windows, shift-rightclick in the folder and choose "Open Command Window Here' or use the [cd](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) command to navigate to the folder containing your project.

Comment: If you navigated to a different folder, the error will be different - specifically the lines that say `ENOENT: no such file or directory`.